# How do you collaborate in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, version-control, devops, collaboration

My friend and I want to work on a Unity project together but we do not know-how. How would my friend and I both be able to have access to the files and the project at the same time?

Comment: Use Unity Collab here is the documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityCollaborate.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various approaches, depending on the team's preferences.

- [Unity Collaborate](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityCollaborate.html), that was [upgraded to Plastic SCM (Source Code Management)](https://blog.unity.com/games/upgrading-from-collaborate-to-unity-plastic-scm). This is part of [Unity Teams](https://unity.com/products/unity-teams). [Learn more about Plastic SCM here](https://unity.com/solutions/version-control). Here is a table with the current [pricing](https://unity.com/products/unity-devops/pricing) (5th May 2022):

[image]

- Using a version control system, such as [GitHub](https://github.com), [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/product), or [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com).
- (Outdated) A couple of years ago GitHub was working on [GitHub for Unity](https://unity.github.com) ([it was introduced in 2017](https://github.blog/2017-03-02-introducing-github-for-unity/), but [version 1.0 only came out in 2018](https://github.blog/2018-06-18-announcing-github-for-unity-1.0/)). However as this doesn't seem to be updated for quite a while I cannot recommend this option ([repo](https://github.com/github-for-unity/Unity) / [Unity's Asset Store](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/version-control/github-for-unity-118069)).

For smaller teams, which is your specific case, I have found Unity's Collaborate quite helpful. And, depending on one's level of expertise, it should be a faster approach to get things up and running.

If you are a student, you may want to consider [Unity Student's pack](https://unity.com/products/unity-student).

This type of questions are related with the Development Operations (DevOps). [Here][16] one can read more about Unity's suite of products related to version control (Plastic SCM), automated builds (Cloud Build), and automatic testing (Automated QA).

Additional relevant readings:

- [What are version control systems?](https://unity.com/solutions/version-control-systems)
- [Understand source code management](https://unity.com/solutions/source-code-management)

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend that you get to grips with Git version control system. This technology is very important in development!
Start with Gitlab or Github. Once you understand this you can think about how you want to work together on your Unity project.

I would look at that first before you start with a tool like Unity Collaborate or something similar. It makes more sense to start with Git first in my opinion.